# Where are the built in MVC scaffolding T4 templates?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

With the newest MVC tools, when I add a controller, I get scaffolding for the controller code as well as the CRUD Views.  I'm not asking about how to override templates.  I understand that I can override the T4 scaffolding templates, but I would like to see the existing built-in scaffolding templates that support the default code generation.

**Where can I find the T4 code that supports the built-in/default scaffolding for MVC Views and Controllers?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [Hansleman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ModifyingTheDefaultCodeGenerationscaffoldingTemplatesInASPNETMVC.aspx):

```
C:\Program Files (or x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp (or Visual Basic)\Web\MVC (or 2) 3\CodeTemplates
```