# Can MVC Scaffolding T4 Templates be installed using VSIX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, t4, vsix

I have a MVC template that should be installed in

> Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp (or Visual Basic)\Web\MVC (or 2)
>   3\CodeTemplates

as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7249414/where-are-the-built-in-mvc-scaffolding-t4-templates).

Is there a way to include this on a VSIX package?

Comment: Do you mean you have a T4 template and want to publish it as VSIX?

Comment: Exactly, I would like to add one more option in the AddView dialog.

Comment: It's possible - take a look at my github (https://github.com/moozzyk/) - there are projects for my 3 templates that are published on Visual Studio Gallery. You can build everything in VS. If you are using VS2012 you want to look at the project for EF6. The others are for VS2010. I am planning to write a post that explains how to create VSIX step by step.

Comment: Not sure but I think by Add View you mean EF views. I was meaning MVC Views (contextual menu on the /Views/ folder on a ASP.Net App). Did you mean that?

Comment: I mentioned views just to point you to the right projects - these projects are all about shipping T4 templates as VSIX packages which I understand you are after. My intention was to point you to these project so that you could create your own project with your own T4 based on what I did.

Comment: I appreciate your help. In fact, I think I already checked out your project by downloading it from the VS gallery before asking the question!. My main problem here is how to tell MVC tooling to discover my t4 template so it's integrated in the normal workflow. I think the only way is to place the templates in the folder above, but I don't see how to do that using VSIX. Thank's a lot for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know. I thought that if you have a T4 template it will be by default executed when you build or you can enforce execution by right clicking and selecting "run custom tool". I have not played with MVC too much so I don't know what the integration between tooling and T4 should look like.

Answer (score 1):

**Manually**

1. Install the Visual Studio 2012 SDK (also available for 2010).
2. Create a VSIX project.
3. Double click the *.vsixmanifest file to open the manifest designer.
4. Add a new project template asset and point it to your template *.zip file.

**Template Wizard Extension**

Additionally, you can try the template Template Wizard Extension if you want to export a template and VSIX in one step:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff527343(v=vs.100).aspx